# .NET set collection using identity

Tags: .net, collections

Does there exist any set-like collection (like `HashSet<T>`) that works on identity instead of hashcodes/equality? If I just want to have a 1000 (or many more) objects that I don't care whether or not are considered equal, but need to check if I've already received said object previously?

**[Edit]**
Spesifically, in this case I'm handed a `GameObject` (from a game engine, of which I have no control and I cannot change the code of) to be stored in a set. Now in general, using hashcodes and equality is probably fine, it just hit me that (at least in this particular case) I don't need it. I just need to make sure that a object doesn't get re-added to the collection. I don't know if `GetHashCode` or equality is overridden in the class I'm handling either.

**[Edit 2]**
So, to attempt to describe more what I mean by identity. If you in C# create two `Object`s (using `new Object()`) there are two ways to check if they are "equal". One is to check for equality (either using `Object.Equals` or `==`), the other is to check if they are *the same object* (reference-equality). If I'm not mistaken, in VB, you can do this with `obj1 Is obj2`. This is checking by identity, instead of by equality. In other words, I'm looking for a collection that works on reference-equality, instead of the overridable kind.

Comment: What if you create a custom type that has a hash set and checks this condition before doing an insert?

Comment: Perhaps `Dictionary<TUniqueKey, TValue>` will suffice?

Comment: That wouldn't much help, because I'm handed `TValue`s by consumers of my class. Ie., I have no way of binding it to a `TUniqueKey` (without having a `Dictionary<TValue, TUniqueKey>` which sort of defeats the whole purpose).

Comment: @Alxandr What you mean about **identity** ??

Comment: See update for more details on what I mean.

Comment: @Alxandr I changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that implement IList interface, inside this class you will have a List, that will hold object, you will pass through list almost all methods, except: **Add**, **Contains** **Insert** and **SET[Index]**, and you will use the method `ReferenceEquals` to check if both object are have the same reference.

If you have this class

```
public class Person
{
    protected bool Equals(Person other) => Id == other?.Id;

    public override int GetHashCode() => Id;

    public static bool operator ==(Person left, Person right) => Equals(left, right);

    public static bool operator !=(Person left, Person right) => !Equals(left, right);

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Person);
}
```

Then if you run this code

```
var person = new Person() { Id = 1 };
var person2 = new Person() { Id = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(person == person2);
```

You will get that both person are equals.

Now lets create a `ListByReference<T>`

```
public class ListByReference<T> : IList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _list;

    public ListByReference()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (ObjectExists(item))
            return;
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear() => _list.Clear();

    public bool Contains(T item) => ObjectExists(item);

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex) => _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);

    public bool Remove(T item) => _list.Remove(item);

    public int Count => _list.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;
    public int IndexOf(T item) => _list.IndexOf(item);

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        if (ObjectExists(item))
            return;
        _list.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index) => _list.RemoveAt(index);

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return _list[index]; }
        set
        {
            if (ObjectExists(value))
                return;
            _list[index] = value;
        }
    }

    private bool ObjectExists(T item) => _list.Any(i => ReferenceEquals(i, item));
}
```

Then we can test our class

```
var person = new Person() { Id = 1 };
var person2 = new Person() { Id = 1 };

var listByReference = new ListByReference<Person>();

listByReference.Add(person);
listByReference.Add(person2);
listByReference.Add(person);

Console.WriteLine(listByReference.Count);
Console.WriteLine(listByReference.Contains(person));
Console.WriteLine(listByReference.Contains(person2));
Console.WriteLine(listByReference.Contains(new Person() { Id = 1 }));
```

The output is

> 2
>
> True
>
> True
>
> False

As you can see I called the add 3 times, but I have only 2 persons on list, because the first one was already added.

I choose not throw exception when try to add some object that already is in, but you can modify if you like.

Comment: This can't be used though if I can't edit the class itself. Unless ofcause I wrap it. A struct wrapper might be able to achieve the same effect...

Comment: @Alxandr you can edit the class, just do it `values[1].Property = value`

Comment: Like, for instance, say it's strings I need to check by identity (or a class by a framework I use). I can't add `Id` to them.

Comment: @Alxandr can you give an example in your question?

Comment: If not overridden, `==` will compare by reference (returns true if variables point to the same object). Of course, for reference types (other than string).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx

Comment: @Shadowed yeah, but the OP doesn't have the class code of the object that he want to put in collection, so its best to use `ReferenceEquals` instead use `==`

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment should have been to the question, not this answer. Anyway, I agree about `ReferenceEquals` if you can't know if `==` is overridden.

Comment: While this would work in general, it defeats the purpose. The point was to have a `Set` (O(1) lookup time). I guess you can't make sets based on reference in .NET, cause the objects may be moved around by the GC. So the correct answer is probably just that such a thing does not exist, and to a certain extent cannot.